# Change iframe src from another webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have a webpage that show a iframe, instaframe.html.
I´m trying to create a webpage where I can set the iframe src with a input field. I have no clue what so ever how to do this or if its possible at all..

Instaframe.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>InstaFrame</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/in/?h=bWU5fGlufDEyNXwzfDN8fG5vfDV8bm9uZXxvblN0YXJ0fG5vfG5v&ve=070515" 
            title="Instagram Widget" 
            class="snapwidget-widget" 
            allowTransparency="true" 
            frameborder="0" 
            scrolling="no" 
            style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:390px; height:390px"
    </body>
</html>
```

Instaframe.html is on my raspberry pi connected to a monitor in a photo frame on my wall. My goal is to be able to surf to a webpage on the raspberry and from there change the iframe src that are showed on the monitor. I have a php webserver installed and running on the raspberry pi.

Comment: Depends, most of the time you can't do that at all, as the same-origin policy prevents access to cross-origin iFrames.

Comment: @adeneo the cross origin policy does **not** affect the `src` attribute. It only affects accessing the window/DOM of the frame and anything to do with requests (AJAX, sockets etc.). `X-Frame-Options` maybe prevent embedding but this is not the case for snapwidget.com

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
<input type="text" id="iframe_src" value="http://snapwidget.com/" />
<input type="button" id="iframe_src_button" value="Go!" />
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("iframe_src_button").onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("iframe").src = document.getElementById("iframe_src").value
    };
</script>
```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4b60o7h1/

This works because snapwidget.com doesn't return a `X-Frame-Options` header that might block embedding. For instance Google and StackOverflow do return this header so you can't embed them.